# *ngFor adds on existing table rows instead of updating them

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

on sonic 3 I am using SQLite plugin then
I am inserting data into SQLite database and retrieving that data and displaying it in my template.

my typescript file

```
    saveData() {

        this.sqlite.create({
          name: 'ionicdb.db',
          location: 'default'
        }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
          db.executeSql('INSERT INTO meal VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [this.data.meal, this.data.pro, this.data.carb, this.data.fat, this.data.sugar, this.data.salt, this.today])
            .then(res => {
              console.log(res);
              this.toast.show("Data saved", '5000', 'center').subscribe(
                toast => {
                  this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
                }
              );
            })
            .catch(e => {
              console.log(e);
              this.toast.show(this.today, '5000', 'center').subscribe(
                toast => {
                  console.log(toast);
                }
              );
            });
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
          this.toast.show('nope 2', '5000', 'center').subscribe(
            toast => {
              console.log(toast);
            }
          );
        });
        this.getData();

      }

    getData() {
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'ionicdb.db',
      location: 'default'
    }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS meal(rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, meal TEXT, pro INTEGER, carb INTEGER, fat INTEGER, sugar INTEGER, salt INTEGER, date TEXT)', {})
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          this.toast.show("Database saved", '8000', 'center').subscribe(
            toast => {
              this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
            }
          );
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
          this.toast.show("not saved", '8000', 'center').subscribe(
            toast => {
              console.log(toast);
            }
          );
        });
      db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM meal WHERE date(date) = date('now')", {})
        .then(res => {          
          for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
            this.meals.push({ rowid: res.rows.item(i).rowid, meal: res.rows.item(i).meal, pro: res.rows.item(i).pro, carb: res.rows.item(i).carb, fat: res.rows.item(i).fat, sugar: res.rows.item(i).sugar, salt: res.rows.item(i).salt, date: res.rows.item(i).date})
          }
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));


    }).catch(e => console.log(e));

  }
```

my template

```
 <tr  *ngFor="let meal of meals ;" >

        <td id="iki">{{meal.meal}}</td>
        <td id="bir">{{meal.pro}}</td>
        <td id="bir">{{meal.carb}}</td>
        <td id="bir">{{meal.fat}}</td>
        <td id="bir">{{meal.sugar}}</td>
        <td id="bir">{{meal.salt}}</td>
        <td id="bir">
          <button ion-button color="danger" style="width:12%;height:30px;" item-left ion-button (click)="removeMeal(meal.rowid)">
            <ion-icon name="remove"></ion-icon>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

the problem is whenever I make an update with saveData() function, instead of updating the table it adds all elements from the beginning. First, I made a research and Thought that I should use **TracBy** then I realized even without using it I could only know it by the console, not from the users' point of view.

example from my table:
Before saveData();

```
meal1  20 20 20 20
meal2  30 30 30 30
```

after saveData();

```
meal1  20 20 20 20
meal2  30 30 30 30
meal1  20 20 20 20
meal2  30 30 30 30
meal3  40 40 40 40
```

my expectation:

```
meal1  20 20 20 20
meal2  30 30 30 30
meal3  40 40 40 40
```

how can I solve this situation?
thank you!

Comment: Are you sure saveData method called once, but not 3 times? Can you check it by using breakpoint on it?

Comment: even if I call it there times should it just show the 3 rows ?

Comment: If it called 3 times then you will get 3 rows in database table. Right?

Comment: yes, but I used trackBy with respect to the rowid and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have emptied the array with `this.meals=[];` before pushing new data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe is that you are pushing it to the existing array

Change the for, replace it with

```
this.meals = res.rows;
```

When you push (array.push()) you add the items to the existing array. This is why the ngFor renders the previous data.

PS: you don't need to iterate over the array and push the items built with the same keys.

Comment: when I do that no data is shown even if I add any. (even tough it does add to database)

Comment: I don't know any other way than for loop since I have multiple rows in my database.